# HANA Where Filter With EXTRACT YEAR

Tags: hana

I'm using the following SQL script:

```sql
    SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM FPCOMMNPERIOD_CALC) As COMMYEAR
    FROM "_SYS_BIC"."tfx.adhoc.Greg_Test/CV_SALES_W_PRICINGCV_TEST"
    GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM FPCOMMNPERIOD_CALC)
    ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM FPCOMMNPERIOD_CALC) ASC;
```

and it operates just fine, outputting a list from 2007 to 2018. However, if we include the below line:

```sql
    WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM FPCOMMNPERIOD_CALC) IN (2011, 2012, 2013)
```

to subset certain years, HANA returns:

> Could not execute 'SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM FPCOMMNPERIOD_CALC) As COMMYEAR FROM ...' in 114 ms 271 µs .
>
> [303]: invalid DATE, TIME or TIMESTAMP value: search table error:  [6931] attribute value is not a date or wrong syntax

I'm using Tableau to connect to HANA, which generates a similar filtering statement. I've tried even filtering for 1 value as text `= '2018'` but HANA continues to output the error.

The column FPCOMMNPERIOD_CALC is a calculated column, where ZTFPCOMN is for e.g. '2018007' (2018 period 007):

```
leftstr("ZTFPCOMN",4)+'-'+rightstr("ZTFPCOMN",2)+'-'+'01')
```

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. What version of HANA are you using?

Comment: Agreed, based on version history from Hana Studio I believe it's HANA 2.0.012